# Duration from timestamps?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have entry date in DD.MM.YYYY HH:MM:SS format, quantity and worker name

This is how the data looks like:

```
ENTRY_DATE          WORKER_ID   QUANTITY
04.06.2018 7:54     34020893    7
04.06.2018 7:56     34020893    8
04.06.2018 7:54     33236047    9
11.04.2018 1:08     21753391    10
11.04.2018 1:07     22165585    4
12.04.2018 13:33    85048731    3
13.06.2018 1:28     49359718    8
11.04.2018 7:38     21753391    2
11.04.2018 7:26     23978525    8
11.04.2018 7:24     60054767    5
11.04.2018 7:23     55013910    6
11.04.2018 7:26     85048731    1
11.04.2018 7:29     85048731    1
11.04.2018 7:28     76149054    6
11.04.2018 7:29     85048731    1
11.04.2018 7:30     6142395     5
11.04.2018 7:30     12696509    4
11.04.2018 7:28     73004538    7
11.04.2018 7:30     85048731    2
11.04.2018 7:30     85048731    8
11.04.2018 7:27     50991253    5
11.04.2018 7:30     98493524    8
11.04.2018 7:28     28851347    2
11.04.2018 7:30     79286529    3
12.04.2018 8:24     34020893    7
12.04.2018 13:24    21753391    1
12.04.2018 13:31    82997006    9
12.04.2018 13:32    21753391    4
12.04.2018 13:25    34020893    3
```

What I need:
WORKER_ID worked for x hours and processed y units

```
WORKER_ID   TOTAL_QUANTITY  TOTAL_HOURS_WORKED 
82997006    50              08:36:56
```

It is similar problem to this: https://www.interfacett.com/blogs/how-to-use-values-from-previous-or-next-rows-in-a-query-in-sql-server/

but the start and end time is not between two rows but between multiple rows.

My current SQL:

```
SELECT
     TO_CHAR(be.ENTRY_DATE, 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS') AS ENTRY_DATE
    ,WORKER_ID
    ,QUANTITY
FROM BINEDIT_ENTRIES
WHERE REGION_ID = 2
AND be.ENTRY_DATE BETWEEN TO_DATE({RUN_DATE_YYYYMMDD}, 'YYYYMMDD')-1
        AND TO_DATE({RUN_DATE_YYYYMMDD}, 'YYYYMMDD')
```

Comment: Please make your question clearer by including sample worker names, and how your desired result should look like and why.

Comment: Can you edit your question again and include what  your expected output from the sample data should look like

Comment: `TO_CHAR` and `TO_DATE` are not sql server functions. Please tag the correct dbms.

Comment: What does the `quantity` signify?

Comment: Edite, @AjayGupta quantity(number) of units processed.

Comment: How can you have "units processed" on entry of a worker?

Comment: Each row represents a work move. i.g. worker 34020893 processed 15 units and worked 2 minutes on 04.06.2018. Does that make sense?

Comment: Is the time of a record the time a worker finished their work or the time they started it? And how to get the counter part? It seems like the data lacks the information to calculate a duration, how lonk a worker worked.

Comment: It is time stamp when he scanned items. He scans and enters quantity.

Comment: What datatype is the `ENTRY_DATE` column defined with?

Comment: Datetype is Datetime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is that I sorted by date and used LAG function fixed on worker.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017